# Impossible to get express work in an existing project on Vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, vercel

**Yesterday I deployed an application on Vercel using only ReactJS.**

**Today, I decided to create an API for my application,**

Just to be clear, i have a folder containing the react app, inside that I created a folder called "api" like the tutorial below

I followed the tutorial on the page: https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel#standalone-express

I redirected the routes as shown in the tutorial,
but I can't get my API to work,
I've tried with Postman too and it returns the React HTML source code:

[image: The API Reponse, i got that instead of "Hello World"]

[image: This is my vercel.json]

```
 async function fetchInfo() {
    const url = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/hello";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    console.log(response)
    const data = await response.json();
    setResult(data)
    console.log(data)
  }
```

I'm stuck to this day and that's why I've come to ask you for help.

I added the vercel.json in my github repository to expect that work but nothing..

What I have tried:

It work in localhost,
I get the response of my API

I added the vercel.json in my github repo,
I added express to my /api folder,
Tried, not working, so i deleted express,
I Added express to root folder which contains the react app, not working too,
Asked IA (lol)

Answer (score 0):

For your information, I have found the cause of my problem,
It is mandatory to call your folder "api" and the file "index.js", what caused the problem for me was that my folder was called /server and my file /api